# i m using user agent for scraping secured site,still i got this error; raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-error

I m scraping and parsing the html content of secured website justdial.com into a csv file ,since i m using user agent also but still i m getting this error- raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: Forbidden .
My code is -

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}    

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/311/B2b_fil'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())

html= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

After printing response , i have to parse the content from html to csv file but it is giving this error

```
  File "<ipython-input-21-c589d79bf43d>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/justdial.py', wdir='C:/Users')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/justdial.py", line 21, in <module>
html= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Forbidden
```

Comment: In your second request you don't set a user-agent. But why don't you use the html of the first request?

Comment: @t.m.adam Actually in first request i m getting the data of website in htnl form , but i m not getting how to parse it in the csv file,any idea about it ?

Comment: I think that should be a new question (or you could change this question to describe the broblem)